# How to separate custom field values into individual links

Tags: php, database

I got a comma separated list of names contained in a custom field.
Each post owns this custom field full of names comma separated.
I'm using the following code to try and make those names clickable individually.

There must be an error in my code tho, as it is including all names altogether.
Please give me a tips to fix this.

```
<?php 
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MY_LIST_OF_NAMES', true ); 
$value_array = explode(',', $value); 
foreach($array as $value_array) { 
    $url = esc_url( 'http://mywebsite.com/names/' . $value_array );
    if ( '' !== $url ) { 
        $display = esc_html( $value_array );
        print "<a href='$url'>$display</a>"; 
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Make sure you understand what __each__ variable means. I don't see where `$array` defined forexample.

Comment: can you give any expected output example ?

Comment: @Ragupathi
Like for example imdb, under the voice "movie cast" you can click on single actor names and each of them brings to a specific page. Same for me, I'm listing some book authors on each post, and need to do the same.

Comment: @u_mulder you're right... I'm sorry, I'm just a newbie, so the max I can do is to copy existing codes found somewhere and try to edit them by my own...

Answer (score 0):

error on foreach()
sample example

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a); //just print array value

foreach($a as $value){
echo $value;
echo "<br />";
}
```

your code

```
<?php 
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MY_LIST_OF_NAMES', true ); 
$value_array = explode(',', $value); 
foreach($value_array as $array ) { 
$remove_space = str_replace(' ', '', $array);
    $url = esc_url( 'http://mywebsite.com/names/' . $remove_space);
    if ( '' !== $url ) { 
        $display = esc_html( $array);
        print "<a href='$url'>$display</a>"; 
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working, but partially. Given I have also added this part in the end { echo ',';}; in order to separate names by comma, in both cases only the first name listed gets correctly linked to the url; while all remaining names start with a blank space just after the http string and also between first and last name (ex. http://mywebsite.com/names/ agatha christie ...How to solve this? :) need to delete the initial blank space, and sub the intermedial one contained between first name and last name, replacing it with -

Comment: i want    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MY_LIST_OF_NAMES', true );  
this response can only will help you buddy

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Notyourkindofpeople I want $value sample array format

Comment: I still don't understand what you're expecting me to provide you as $value sample array format... I'm telling you that your current code ends up with this: <a href='http://mywebsite.com/names/Agatha%20Christie'>Agatha Christie</a>,<a href='http://mywebsite.com/names/%20Mario%20Rossi%20Russo'> Mario Rossi Russo</a>
 ... Can we get rid of those blank spaces '%20' and replace the %20 included between first and last name with a -?

Comment: You forgot that FirstName-LastName need a '-' rather than removing the blank space :) I'd rather do $remove_firstTOlastNAMEspace = str_replace(' ', '-', $array);
and then create another string to remove the blank space listed at start of names only :) (no idea how to type it in code)